# Is it possible to return HTTP response code to the browser using pl/sql?

Tags: apache, http, plsql, http-headers, oracle11g

I am working on web application written in pl/sql . It uses Basic Authentication. Now there is no efficient way of logging out unless you close the browser.
This is what I am using on the log off page

```
owa_util.mime_header('text/html', FALSE, NULL);
v_browser:= owa_util.get_cgi_env('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
owa_cookie.send('WDB_GATEWAY_LOGOUT', 'YES', path=>'/');
-- Close the HTTP header
owa_util.status_line(401,'Unauthorzed Access', true);
owa_util.http_header_close;
```

Is this even possible. I'll appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, oracle has package called [utl_http](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_http.htm) and [utl_url](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_url.htm#1001422)

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_http.htm#1012294):

```
HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 401
```

***RESP Type***

This PL/SQL record type is used to represent an HTTP response.

**Syntax**

```
TYPE resp IS RECORD (
   status_code    PLS_INTEGER,
   reason_phrase  VARCHAR2(256),
   http_version   VARCHAR2(64),
);
```

Comment: Thank you , So how I do actually pass these values manually. Can we pass the server response as 401 .I tried using set_header and set_authentication but those do work.I am fairly new to this .